# SpannableStringBuilder set ClickableSpan more than once, can't click

Tags: android

I need to attach the same `CharacterStyle` to multiple regions, so I use `CharacterStyle.wrap()`. Then all regions are underlined but not clickable.
What's the possible reason?

```
 ssb.setSpan(CharacterStyle.wrap(clickableSpan), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: i experience the same - did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

This probably qualifies as a bug in the Android framework. The core issue is either the implementation of the method [`SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#getSpans%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29) or the implementation of the [`LinkMovementMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.html) that should handle `ClickableSpan`s.

The [`onTouchEvent()` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java#LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent%28android.widget.TextView%2Candroid.text.Spannable%2Candroid.view.MotionEvent%29) of the `LinkMovementMethod` requests all `ClickableSpan` instances from the `SpannableStringBuilder` with [`getSpans()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#getSpans%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29) that filters its spans basically with `instanceof`. But problem is if you use `CharacterStyle.wrap()` your span is no longer a `ClickableSpan` instance, but a `CharacterStyle.Passthrough` instance instead. Therefore `getSpans()` does not return it anymore and it's no longer clickable.

Note that the text appearance (drawing) is not affected by this, thus it still looks like a `ClickableSpan`.

Now, to fix the problem you either have to extend `SpannableStringBuilder` to fix the `getSpans()` implementation (which is too complex), or extend the `LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent()` implementation to filter the `ClickableSpan` manually. You can find an [example here](https://gist.github.com/Floern/abdb85b4960453d672d9) that then can be used with

```
textview.setMovementMethod(new FixedLinkMovementMethod());
```

But then again, maybe it would be easier just to copy a span manually if its a `ClickableSpan` instead of using `CharacterStyle.wrap()`.